# Reading CSV file into Corpus - tm package in R

Tags: r, tm

I would like to read the contents of the csv file into a dataframesource but when i try to create a corpus it always says

```
**argument "x" is missing, with no default**
```

The code is

```
corpus1 <- Corpus(object=ds, 
    readerControl=list(reader=readTabular(mapping=m),language="en"))
```

`ds` is a dataframesource & `m` is a list which assigns content,topic etc to the fields of the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look at the help for `?Corpus` indicates that this function takes two arguments:

- `x`
- `readerControl`

Since you provide an argument `object`, but no `x`,  your code should probably look like this:

```
corpus1 <- Corpus(x=ds, readerControl=list(...)
```